# Animation Nodes: add a new shape, like UV sphere

Tags: animation-nodes

I'm very new to Animation Nodes, and I'd like to see if I can do some parametric object creation with it (I tried sverchok before that looks great also, but I got some unexplained segfault so I'm trying to see if AN is more stable). Unfortunately, I can't find how to perform this very simple task: create an UV sphere (or a cube/any basic mesh...) directly from Animation Nodes (the `object instancier` node seems to refer to a node already present in the scene, which is not really what I need).

Is it possible? If not, could you explain why this basic feature is not present?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name says Animation Nodes it is mainly made for animations, so there are few mesh generators than sverchok.You can always create an uv sphere in blender and insert it in AN by the mesh or object nodes input.

Comment: I see, thank you!